# function.file-get-contents - failed to open stream

Tags: php, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file_get_contents with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988707/file-get-contents-with-query-string)

I'm using the `file_get_contents` function but although returning the correct output, it is still showing this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(secure/validate.php?cardnumber=1234567) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in ...
```

The scenario is card number validation and in `validatecard.php` there is a simple if statement:

```
if (isset($_GET['cardnumber']) && ($_GET['cardnumber'] == "12345")) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "INVALID CARD";
}
```

My code is:

```
$cardnumber = $_POST["cardnumber"];
$url = "secure/validate.php?cardnumber=" . $cardnumber;
if (file_get_contents($url) != "OK"){
    $order_error_msg = "Invalid card number";
} else { ....
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Path is correct? $_POST['cardnumber'] is set? allow_url_fopen = On in phpinfo() ?

Comment: you are trying to open a local path like a URL.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Well, it seems like you don't have allow_url_fopen set in your php.ini</strike> @Gordon is correct, this is not a url_fopen issue. It's actually failing because using file_get_contents on the local file will actually get you the *code* for the file, not the PHP-processed result of running that file. To get it to work as you wanted, you'd need to hit apache/PHP by prepending "https://localhost/" to the url, and enabling allow_url_fopen.

But also this looks like a very worrying piece of code; you should do as little as possible with CC numbers in the code. By using file_get_contents and a card number on the get string, it opens up the possibility of the number being logged somewhere.

A much more secure implementation would look something like this:

validatecard.php

```
function checkCard($card) {
  if ($card == "12345")) {
      return "OK";
  } else {
      return "INVALID CARD";
  }
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
include('secure/validatecard.php');

$cardnumber = $_POST["cardnumber"];
if (checkCard($cardnumber) != "OK"){
    $order_error_msg = "Invalid card number";
} else { ....
```

That way your checkCard function is more re-usable, and you don't have to ferry the card number around so much.

If you decide to go with the file_get_contents approach and hit https://localhost/secure/validatecard.php?card=12345 then the credit card numbers *will* get logged in your apache access logs in plain text. This is verging on criminally negligent, don't do it.

also, as per Gordon's advice, make sure that you're using https all the way through.

You might consider hiring in a contractor with experience writing shopping carts/checkouts. These things are important to get right, and can be insecure in subtle ways if you're not experienced.

Comment: @Gordon I didn't add the POST requirement, that's just copied from the OP's code. I added the use of an include to check the card number instead of hitting another script with the card in the get parameter.

Comment: its better now. thanks for making the changes. i reverted the downvote. you might want to stress that the OP should use HTTPS though and point out that there is laws governing how to handle CC transactions on the web.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your  `php.ini` configuration allows for opening urls?

you can check using `phpinfo()` and searching for `allow_url_fopen`

also, as another poster [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061828/487891) , using GET for this kind of stuff isn't really ideal (read: really really bad). if you're keen on making a request to another page, rather than using a file (if that other page is not on your server, for example), try using `cURL` and do a POST request

Comment: allow_url_fopen has nothing to do with it

Comment: well, the docs say otherwise :  http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php (check notes)

Comment: but the OP is not passing in a URL. hes passing a local path.

Comment: true, he's not passing a URL and that may be a mistake or may be his intended use. until the OP clears that up, both are possible