# require_once() breaking array of urls that should generate OpenGraph tags?

Tags: php, foreach, require-once, facebook-opengraph

Having trouble with this code, wondering if I'm trying to achieve something  impossible. I'm using the [OpenGraph PHP library](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph/blob/master/OpenGraph.php)

I want to fetch an array of urls, send them each through OpenGraph.php and then echo out a few Open Graph tags from that url.

The require_once() function seems to break the array, because I think it narrows the retrieval of $urls[$i] to OpenGraph.php? Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
<?php
$urls = array();
$paras = array();
$c=0;
foreach($_POST as $variable){
    if($i==1){
        array_push($urls,$variable);
        $i++;
    }else{
        array_push($paras,$variable);
        $i=1;
    }
    $c++;
};

echo'<table>';
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    require_once('OpenGraph.php');
    $graph = OpenGraph::fetch("$urls[$i]");
    echo $graph->title;
    echo'<tr><td>'.$paras[$i].'</td></tr>'
}
echo'</table>';
?>
```

Thanks!

EDIT

The require_once() function was not the problem and it certainly didn't need to be in the loop. The issue was running the file on my localhost PHP was not correctly configured for the task. Moving it onto server that was configured correctly fixed it.

Comment: Why would you put `require_once()` in a loop?

Comment: @Sam Dufel: I bet because of copy-pasting rocks ;-)

Comment: Okay, so I it's dumb to have require_once('OpenGraph.php'); in the loop. I'll call it before the loop and if its not working up it has nothing to do with an array. I am a php beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The require_once() function was not the problem and it certainly didn't need to be in the loop. The issue was running the file on my [localhost PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061759/function-file-get-contents-failed-to-open-stream) was not correctly configured for the task. Moving it onto a proper server that was configured correctly fixed it.